# How to remove or solve a possible shirk Issue from Verse (43:84)?

Tags: quran, tafseer, arabic, shirk

If we take the Verse ([43:84](http://legacy.quran.com/43/84))literally, it would mean that there's a deity in the heaven and an other on earth, which is a clear conflict to our monotheistic view (tawhid). Maybe the translation of Muhsin Khan (see also the translation of Dr. Ghali) shows this issue more clearly than any other:

> It is He (Allah) Who is the only Ilah (God to be worshipped) in the heaven and the only Ilah (God to be worshipped) on the earth. And He is the All-Wise, the All-Knower.

The linguistic issue here is: that the noun deity (Ilaah إله) here is nakirah نكرة -which means it is a noun which doesn't begin with the "al ال"- (instead of al-Ilaah الإله) in both cases and if it is repeated that way it means in Arabic language that both nouns are different. For example in surat [a-Sharh](http://legacy.quran.com/94/5-6) where hardship and ease both have been quoted twice (but only the ease was a nakirah), we find in a [narration](http://sunnah.com/urn/509670):

> ...Whatever hardship befalls a believing slave, Allah will make an opening for him after it, and a hardship will not overcome two eases. ...

Some scholars also refer a similar saying to our Prophet (peace be upon him) (Here an Arabic [Fatwa](https://islamqa.info/ar/137151) about the qualification of these ahadith).

But how to solve this issue? I know it is easy to explain the issue which may appear in the meaning of the Verse (and honestly I know it as I've read enough tafsirs of the Verse)

I recall that there's even a linguistic solution, it would be great if anybody could provide and explain this also!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If we take the Verse (43:84)literally, it would mean that there's a deity in the heaven and an other on earth

No, it would not mean that if you take it literally(and we always should). the verse means that `Allah is a deity in heaven , (and also) a deity on earth.`

who said

> and an other on earth !!?

the verse only means

> and on earth

---

EDIT:
as for the linguistic issue:
you said

> and if it is repeated that
>   way it means in Arabic language that both nouns are different.

nakirah نكره does not always mean different things.

I give you an example: suppose our friends are going to have dinner together in Ahmed's home at night , on the way to Ahmed home that night there was a big strange star shown up in the sky, what the friends are going to tell Ahmed when they arrive at Ahmeds home ?

**first person :** Ahmed, I saw **a star** on the way to you
لقد رأيت **نجما** في الطريق إليك

**second person :** Ahmed, I saw **a star** on the way to you
لقد رأيت **نجما** في الطريق إليك

**third person :** Ahmed, I saw **a star** on the way to you
لقد رأيت **نجما** في الطريق إليك

note that the three persons when they talk about the star , they said **(a star)** - nakirah , they didn't say (the star !), although they all mean the same exact star.

**Nakirah does not always used to reference different things, sometimes it mean the same thing , and sometimes they don't**

---

EDIT: 
also this is much better example quoted from [tarek](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/8252/tarek) comment, that shows how to repeat nakirah in the same sentence while mean the same thing

> The star that you saw yesterday is **a star** that belongs to the Milky
>   Way galaxy and **a star** that has never been seen so shiny before!

---

EDIT: 
 brother, you had the answer in the comments to your question in the [youtube video](https://youtu.be/_oOOlS0idN0?t=4m31s)  that [Laconic](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/16130/laconic) give it to you.

**El- sharawy** said in the last [25](https://youtu.be/_oOOlS0idN0?t=4m31s) seconds from the video the exact answer that we are looking for.  the Nahw rule that rules this sentence is called `الواصل والموصول` `(elwasel - and elmawsol)` *- I don't know the exact English translation for it but it is something like the (`referenced noun, and referencing noun`)-*

> you can have many nakirah nouns that referencing the same one maarefa (not-nakirah) referenced noun

which means if you had a noun`(mawsool)` that is known(marifa - not nakirah) معرفة which you joined it later with many nakirah nouns `(wasel)`, that means all those nakirat later (referencing nouns- wasel - واصل) referencing the same (referenced noun- mawsool - موصول ), and means the same referenced noun.

let us apply this Nahw rule on our examples , I will put the( `referenced noun` - الموصول - mawsool ) in this `gray background` and the (**referencing nouns** - wasel - واصل) in **bold** for clearity:

> Example - 1  ([43:84](http://legacy.quran.com/43/84))

It is He `(Allah) Who is` **Ilah** (God to be worshipped) in the heaven and  **Ilah** (God to be worshipped) on the earth. And He is the All-Wise, the All-Knower.

وَهُوَ `الَّذِي` فِي السَّمَاءِ **إِلَهٌ** وَفِي الْأَرْضِ **إِلَهٌ** وَهُوَ الْحَكِيمُ الْعَلِيمُ

> Example - 2  [tarek](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/8252/tarek) example

`The star` that you saw yesterday is **a star** that belongs to the Milky
Way galaxy and **a star** that has never been seen so shiny before!

إن `النجمة` التي رأيتها بالأمس هي **نجمة** تنتمى لمجرة درب التبانة, وهي **نجمة** لم تكن يوما بهذا السطوع

Comment: Alright but this isn't an answer of my question i could give you at least 4-5 quotations from tafsir explaining this. But none is considering the linguistic issue which is the main issue of my question.

Comment: @Medi1Saif OK I added a part in the answer that shows you , that you can sometimes - many times -  use nakirah to mean the same other nakirah thing, if it is still unclear tell me

Comment: @Tarek >"valid example" ? , man this is a perfect example of using repeated nakirah in the same sentence to mean the same thing , much mooore better than my example :) thank you

Comment: @Medi1Saif I think we had the answer that we are looking for in El- sharawy video that Laconic commented to you in your question,  I just extracted the Nahw rule from the video and applied it to our examples in the last edit of the answer, I hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: Of course that's the answer I was looking for but it's not possible to mark or accept comments as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Salam.

I am just pointing something here, not necessarily to be real but I concerned with the verse which is 'ilah' doesn't necessarily has one meaning. In arabic ilah can be of god as literally as possible but ilah also has a meaning that is 'something that is worshipped'.

Two translations example:

'La ilaha illa ana'

1. No/nothing worthy of worship except me
2. No god(small g not the big one) except me

I hope it is helping you.

Comment: This is an interesting point however it doesn't provide a hint of an answer.